# How do you implement external authentication for multiple identity providers in Blazor WASM?

Tags: blazor, openid-connect, webassembly

I’m trying to implement external authentication for a Blazor WASM app using multiple external identity providers (Google, Microsoft, Facebook, Twitter). Ideally the login page would show a button for each IP.

It looks like it should be dead simple using the Authentication tools provided and a couple of sites (Okta, Auth0) give excellent instructions on how to implement external authentication for one IP. However, I haven’t been able to find any information about how to implement external authentication for two or more IPs.

I tried the simple-minded approach of calling AddOidcAuthentication twice in Program.cs, once for each provider, and including the information for both providers in appsettings.json, but the login page only displays one of them (of course).

Microsoft’s documentation doesn’t seem to cover this scenario.

Comment: I believe it would just take the last "AddOidcAuthentication" options you put in your program.cs.  
Have you tried having multiple options within the AddOidcAuthentication?

Comment: For instance, it would look something like this sample project (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Security/Authentication/samples/SocialSample) from Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own identityserver, utilizing external auth providers. E.g. Orchard Core comes out of the box with Google, Twtitter, Facebook and Azure.